# How to filter an array based on starting letters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting to get an array based on first letter. But my solution is not work. 
Here's repl link: https://repl.it/@Huu_TruongTruon/ProbableSandyDistributeddatabase`

```js
const firstLetter = (el, letter) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    if (el[i][0] === letter) {
      return true
    }
    return false;
  }
}

const filter = (array, letter, callback) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var newArr = []
    if (callback) {
      newArr.push(array[i])
    }
    return newArr;
  }
}

//uncomment below to test your work
const suppliesArray = ['pencils', 'brush', 'paint', 'clay', 'easel', 'crayons',
  'acrylic', 'glue', 'paper', 'marble', 'water colors'
];
const projectLetter = 'p';
console.log(filter(suppliesArray, projectLetter, firstLetter));
```

This result should log `['pencils', 'paint', 'paper']`

Comment: You have a filter method on the array, you don't need to define your own. It could be as simple as `suppliesArray.filter(x => x[0] === 'p')`. This line `if (callback) {` is a mistake, you dont call your callback. You just test its not missing/falsey.

Answer (score 4):

The function could be as simple as this, using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```
const filter = (array, letter) => array.filter(s => s.startsWith(letter));
```

---

Full snippet:

```js
const filter = (array, letter) => array.filter(s => s.startsWith(letter));

const suppliesArray = ['pencils', 'brush', 'paint', 'clay', 'easel', 'crayons',
  'acrylic', 'glue', 'paper', 'marble', 'water colors'];
  
const result = filter(suppliesArray, 'p');

console.log(result);
```

---

Without using the native `filter()` function:

```js
const filter = (array, letter) => array.reduce((a, s) => s.startsWith(letter) ? [...a, s] : a, []);

const suppliesArray = ['pencils', 'brush', 'paint', 'clay', 'easel', 'crayons',
  'acrylic', 'glue', 'paper', 'marble', 'water colors'];
  
const result = filter(suppliesArray, 'p');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define your `filter()` method, its already available in JavaScript.

Code -

```js
const filterArr = (suppliesArray, projectLetter) => {
  return suppliesArray.filter(x => x[0] === projectLetter);
};

const suppliesArray = ['pencils', 'brush', 'paint', 'clay', 'easel', 'crayons', 
'acrylic', 'glue', 'paper', 'marble', 'water colors'];
const projectLetter = 'p';
console.log(filterArr(suppliesArray, projectLetter));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
You have returned the array `newArray[]` inside the `for` loop. That's the mistake.

```js
const firstLetter = (el, letter) => {
    if(el[0] === letter) {
      return true
    }
    return false;
}

const filter = (array, letter, callback) => {
  let newArr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(callback(array[i], letter)){
      newArr.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

//uncomment below to test your work
const suppliesArray = ['pencils', 'brush', 'paint', 'clay', 'easel', 'crayons', 
'acrylic', 'glue', 'paper', 'marble', 'water colors'];
const projectLetter = 'p';
console.log(filter(suppliesArray, projectLetter, firstLetter));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [String.prototype.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to check the first letter in a sensitive way `suppliesArray.filter(el => el[0].toLowerCase() === projectLetter.toLowerCase())`

Code:

```js
const suppliesArray = ['pencils', 'brush', 'paint', 'clay', 'easel', 'crayons', 'acrylic', 'glue', 'paper', 'marble', 'water colors'];
const projectLetter = 'p';
const result = suppliesArray.filter(el => el[0].toLowerCase() === projectLetter.toLowerCase());

console.log(result);
```